# Changing the look of a subsite to that of a master site on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sub-site, theme

I have my subsite all set up the way I want except the top toolbar is blue instead of grey/black. The standard for all the pages is a custom gray/black look. How can I set the subsite's top toolbar to be the same as the master site's without redoing everything?

Comment: Do you have publishing enabled?

Comment: yes, i currently have publishing enabled

Comment: I have created one subsite with custom template of the main site ,In that I'm not able to find the change look feel in subsite please suggest me with solution.. SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Answer (score 4):

For `Publishing Site` or sites have publishing feature enabled, you can use the `Design Manager` as the following:

**To inherit `Master Page` / `Theme` of the Main Site to the subsites.**

- Look and Feel > Design Manager > `Publish and Apply Design`.

[image]

- For **Site** Master Page Check

  - Reset all subsites to inherit the `Site Master Page` Setting.
- For **System** Master Page

  - Reset all subsites to inherit the `System Master Page` Setting.

[image]

- For **Theme**

  - Reset all subsites to inherit the `theme` of this site.

[image]

> **Note:**  Design Manager is only available on SharePoint Server 2013/2016, it's not available on SharePoint Foundation 2013, Also it's only available with  Publishing sites or on sites Publishing feature enabled. But before enabling the publishing feature it's recommended to check first its effect at [Missing save site as template in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

**To Change a `Site theme` for a specific subsite.**

- Go to Site Settings > Look and Feel > Change the look, select the look as you prefer!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Publishing enabled sites, you can set the master page and css to inherit parent. For that

1. Open sub site settings page
2. Open Look and Feel -> Master Page
3. For Site Master Page - Select Inherit from Parent
4. For System Master Page - Select Inherit from Parent
5. Check - Reset all subsites to inherit the site master page setting
6. Check - Reset all subsites to inherit the system master page setting
7. Click Ok

Comment: There are only these links under look and feel

Look and Feel 

Design Manager 

Title, description, and logo 

Device Channels 

Tree view 

Change the look 

Import Design Package 

Navigation

Comment: Try to activate publishing infrastructure feature like on this picture http://idr.idratherbewritin1.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/2.png and restart server

Answer (score -1):

so you have to change this for the entire sub sites! what a piece of sh!t is sharepoint anyway.  You can't simply change this for one subsite! @##$##!@!!!

Just found this, would be a lot better if people would answer the questions correctly!!!

Goto http://yoursite/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx