# Prevent CSS file from getting localized

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, css, localization, cssregistration

In my master page, I have reference to theme file as-

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
```

My problem is on my site for different locales, the CSS file is getting localized

Like, for en-us site theme CSS reference is from (on initial load) -

```
<site collection url>/_catalogs/theme/Themed/28DE9520/corev15-65D9856.themedcss
```

But for some other locale pt-br, the reference for theme file is like -

```
<site collection url>/_layouts/15/1046/styles/Themable/corev15.css
```

Can I have a solution for this where CSS file is always referenced from -

```
<site collection url>/_catalogs/theme/Themed/28DE9520/corev15-65D9856.themedcss
```

Comment: try adding `Localizable="false"`. I mean `<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>`

Comment: `Localizable` is not a property of `CssRegistration` class

Comment: yeah true. totally overlooked at the question

Comment: Try taking the CSS out of the hive and placing it in the Style Library => en-us => Themable folder at the top level of your site collection.  This is considered best practices for SharePoint 2013 anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using attribute `EnableCssTheming="true"` in `SharePoint:CssRegistration` tag restricts the file to take it from `<site collection url>/_catalogs/theme/Themed/28DE9520/corev15-65D9856.themedcss` path irrespective of user locale

Hence, the solution which worked for me is -

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" EnableCssTheming="true" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the CSS out of the hive and placing it in the Style Library => en-us => Themable folder at the top level of your site collection.  This is considered best practices for SharePoint 2013 anyways.  Also, make sure your css runs after the cores.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration" Name="/Style Library/en-us/Themable/customized.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```

Comment: Using this will hard code the path, but I want specifically the file to be referred automatically from - `<site collection url>/_catalogs/theme/Themed/28DE9520/corev15-65D9856.themedcss` irrespective of Locale

Answer (score 0):

The CSS reference is generic for whatever theme you have active in the site.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
```

The folder id is generated when you **apply a theme** to a specific site:

e.g.
/_catalogs/theme/Themed/**28DE9520**/corev15-65D9856.themedcss

different sites will have different theme folders so you should definitely not use hardcoded paths to the theme file.

Therefore, I suggest you look into an altenative approach:

- Make sure you apply the same theme (aka "Composed Looks") [throughout the sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127971/changing-the-look-of-a-subsite-to-that-of-a-master-site-on-sharepoint-2013)
- See [How to: Make custom CSS files themable in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn266906.aspx)
- Use a custom CSS file stored in either the hive or Style Library